# What does "File exists" error mean?

Tags: openssl, dtls

Call DTLSv1_listen(), return 0.

Then use SSL_get_error() to retrieve error.

```
SSL_error = SSL_ERROR_SYSCALL
errno = 17: "File exists"
```

What does it mean? What file exists?

Thanks a lot for the help.

Answer (score 0):

It would be nice if You were providing some more context. But short googling led to this piece of code and comment:
http://fossies.org/unix/misc/postgresql-9.2.3.tar.gz/dox/fe-secure_8c_source.html
(line #1085)

```
1982          /*
1083          * Cert file exists, so load it.  Since OpenSSL doesn't provide the
1084          * equivalent of "SSL_use_certificate_chain_file", we actually have to
1085          * load the file twice.  The first call loads any extra certs after
1086          * the first one into chain-cert storage associated with the
1087          * SSL_context.  The second call loads the first cert (only) into the
1088          * SSL object, where it will be correctly paired with the private key
1089          * we load below.  We do it this way so that each connection
1090          * understands which subject cert to present, in case different
1091          * sslcert settings are used for different connections in the same
1092          * process.
1093          */
```